# Proxy class for sequences that can be indexable or just iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3.x, I am trying to implement a class that would be a proxy for a sequence given as a parameter. The proxy also takes a function that is called on each element of the input sequence.

What would be the correct way for the proxy class to implement the `__getitem__`, `__iter__` and `__len__` methods dynamically depending on their availability in the input sequence. Here is my attempt at doing this (I am calling my sequences "providers" and the function is a "transform"):

```
class TransformProviderProxy:

    def __init__(self, input_provider, transform):
        self.input_provider = input_provider
        self.transform = transform

    def __iter__(self):
        # Use generator expressions to produce a new iterator when requested
        return (self.transform(data_sample) for data_sample in self.input_provider)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "__getitem__" and hasattr(self.input_provider, "__getitem__"):
            return self._getitem_impl
        elif name == "__len__" and hasattr(self.input_provider, "__len__"):
            return self._len_impl
        else:
            return None

    def _getitem_impl(self, index):
        return self.transform(self.input_provider[index])

    def _len_impl(self):
        return len(self.input_provider)
```

However that fails because it seems that python bypasses `__getattr__` when looking for `__getitem__`. What would be the correct way to do this ?

As a bonus, would there be a way to do this while having my Proxy class inherit dynamically from `collections.abc.Sequence` or `collections.abc.Iterable` depending on the input sequence ?

PS: I also thought about just implementing `__getitem__` anyway and relying on catching TypeError when trying to call it on a non-indexable input sequence, but I would like to be able to check if my proxy class is indexable by looking for the presence of `__getitem__` without having to explicitly call it with an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement `__getitem__` and `__len__`. It will fail with the appropriate error message if the `input_provider` doesn't implement these operations:

```
class TransformProviderProxy:

    def __init__(self, input_provider, transform):
        self.input_provider = input_provider
        self.transform = transform

    def __iter__(self):
        # Use generator expressions to produce a new iterator when requested
        return (self.transform(data_sample) for data_sample in self.input_provider)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.transform(self.input_provider[index])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.input_provider)
```

Just as example:

```
>>> t = TransformProviderProxy(2, lambda x: x+2)
>>> t[1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

>>> t = TransformProviderProxy([1,2,3,4], lambda x: x+2)
>>> t[1]
4
```

Comment: I edited my question just before you posted your answer sorry (you were too fast for me !). I had thought about this but I wanted to be able able to check if my class was indexable (ideally by checking if it was an instance of `collections.abc.Sequence`) without having to explicitly try to index it. Maybe I should just accept that your way is the more pythonic way ?

Comment: Yes, [EAFP (easier to ask forgiveness than permission)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) is considered more "pythonic" than [LBYL (look before you leap)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl). However you might want to checkout the 3rd party module [`wrapt` and it's `ObjectProxy`](http://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrappers.html#proxies-and-wrappers). That could contain some (already built) solution for your immediate problem. Sorry I haven't seen your last paragraph before ... :(